# Mongodb: Can't append to array using string field name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

i am trying to push inside a subarray using $push but got a Mongo error, and not able to get through this after considerable search on google, and findOneAndUpdate didn't worked out so i used find and update separately

```
{ [MongoError: can't append to array using string field name: to]
name: 'MongoError',
err: 'can\'t append to array using string field name: to',
code: 13048,
n: 0,
lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1418993115 },
```

**Schema:**

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({

UserID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
NetworkList: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}],

NetworkRequest: [{
    from: [{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
}],
    to: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
}]

});
```

**Document:**

```
{
"UserID" : ObjectId("549416c9cbe0e42c1adb42b5"),
"_id" : ObjectId("549416c9cbe0e42c1adb42b6"),
"NetworkRequest" : [ 
    {
        "from" : [],
        "to" : []
    }
],
"NetworkList" : [],
"__v" : 0
}
```

**Controller:**

```
exports.update = function(req,res) {
var network = req.network;
var query={'UserID':req.body.UserID};
var update = {$push:{'NetworkRequest.to': req.body.FriendID}};

Network.find(query,function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {

    }
});

Network.update(query,update,{upsert:true},function(err,user){
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {

        console.log('User'+user);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the only problem, but `NetworkRequest` is defined as an object in your schema but in your doc it's an array.  Also, why is the `Network.find` call there?

Comment: Sorry my apologies, NetworkRequest is an Array in Schema and i edited the question now, mongoose findOneAndUpdate was not working as when i used this function, no errors were shown but i was not able to append values to the array in my database, so i used Network.find and Network.update separately, it was working nicely until this error of MongoDb shown as console, please help me out, i hope you understand my situation here and if not, then i will explain it to you in more detail

Comment: The `Network.find` call isn't needed. Just remove it.

Comment: ok! i did but still getting that mongo error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything @cbass said in his answer is correct, but since you don't have a unique identifier in your `NetworkRequest` element to target, you need to do it by position:

```
var query = {'UserID': req.body.UserID};
var update = {$push:{'NetworkRequest.0.to': req.body.FriendID}};
Test.update(query, update, {upsert: true}, function(err, result) { ... });
```

`'NetworkRequest.0.to'` identifies the `to` field of the first element of the `NetworkRequest` array.

Comment: thanks for answer! Can you tell me how can i update two different documents having different ObjectID's inside same UPDATE function?

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Better to post that as a separate question.

Comment: ok this Question i asked here: -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582112/mongoose-update-multiple-documents-with-different-objectid

Answer (score 1):

Your query `var query={'UserID':req.body.UserID};` identifies the document you want to edit. Then you need another query to identify which object in the NetworkRequest array that the `UserID` should be pushed into. Something like below:

```
var query = { 
       'UserID':req.body.UserID,
       'NetworkRequest._id': ObjectId(someNetworkRequestId)
};
```

Then use this update query containing `$` which is the index of the object in the nested array(NetworkRequest)

```
var update = {
         $push:{
            'NetworkRequest.$.to': req.body.FriendID
         }
};
```

Comment: no it's not working when i used $ sign i am getting this error quite different from above error--- MongoError: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.---

Comment: Do you have the id for the networkrequest you want to push into?

Comment: yes i have id that's why i didn't mention client controller side code, as it's not causing any error

Comment: sorry!.i am not able to get this line of code--'NetworkRequest._id': ObjectId(someNetworkRequestId)-- can you help me, what should i refer to ObjectId(someNetworkRequestId), just for information here, UserID is id of logged in user.

Comment: Sorry, now I can see that the NetworkRequest doesn't have an Id. Which makes the push extremely hard. But I don't understad why NetworkRequest is an array. You don't have anything that indetifies it.

Comment: You should probably look in to mongoose save method instead. Se the mongoose docs.

Comment: ok. see take an example here as i am a user i logged into my account and send you a friend request so as you say i can define NetworkRequest as a object not as an array but it's sub field(to and from) should be an array type i think, and i am open to suggestions here as ("to") field will have the ObjectID of user to whom i sent the request and ("from") field should have request's i received, so there will be multiple objectID's here so i thought to define it as an array, now i hope you understand what i am trying and help me to achieve that