# Mongoose update multiple documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert-update

Actually i am using **mongoDB**, and i am able to update document with single ObjectID, so right now i want to perform update on multiple documents having different **ObjectID**, i did considerable search, came to know **{multi:true}** will help to update multiple documents.
Let's say i have

```
var uid = {'Userid': ObjectId(..)};
var id = {'Newid': Object(..)};
```

now i want to perform update on both of these **different documents** having **different ObjectId'** s total **separatley**, so far i tried this considering **"xyz"** and **"abc"** array's in Schema just for demo

```
var update_uid = {$push:{'xyz': some_id}};
var update_id = {$push:{'abc': some_other_id}};

Test.update(uid,id,update_uid,update_id,{multi:true},function(){..});
```

this is wrong i know, i mentioned it for the records just in case, Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: so is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple ids that you want to match you can use the keywork `$in` which checks if there's any matches in the array. Now that you also have multiple properties that you want to check you can user the `$or` keyword, which will find a match if either of the objects in the array matches a document in the database.

```
var userIds = [{'Userid':ObjectId(..)}, {'Userid':ObjectId(..)}];
var newIds = [{'Newid': Object(..)}, {'Newid': Object(..)}];

var query = {
  $or: [{$in: userIds}, {$in: newIds}]
}
```

Comment: But Model.update function only find's the one document and update it, what i want mongoose to find multiple documents like--Model.update(userIds,newIds,update,function{.});-- and update documents inside userIds and newIds separately at same time. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is only the query to find them. You will have to add your queryobject that defines what should be updated, and then, as you mentioned in your question, you will have to add {multi:true}

Comment: with $or either of of object matches document and update on either of document, i want to update both documents??